# Getting Column not found error in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a many to many relationship between users and posts and what I'm trying to do is to get all the posts that is
attached to a user. The problem I'm having is that when I try to get all the posts I don't get them and I get this error
in my dev tools

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'posts.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` = 5 and `posts`.`user_id` is not null and `posts`.`deleted_at` is null)

Here is my code

```
public function getPosts(User $user)
{
    $posts = $user->posts;

    dd($posts);
}
```

Comment: Pls post/include the code of model relationships Post & User, and migration of pivot table

Comment: You are saying you have defined a ManyToMany relationship, but the error clearly shows it's using a oneToMany relationship. You need to check the relationship definition.